# How to reproduce this chart series in R

Tags: r, charts, histogram

I would like to reproduce this chart series in R :
[image]

if I try without package :

```
hist(hist1, col="pink",breaks=100, main=NULL,border = 0)
hist(hist2, col="orange",breaks=100, main=NULL,border = 0)
hist(hist3, col="green",breaks=100, main=NULL,border = 0)
[...]
hist(hist10, col="red",breaks=100, main=NULL,border = 0)
```

The design is really different !
Any suggestions ?

Incidentally, if anyone knows how to apply an identical thereto gray grid?

Comment: this was done with `ggplot2` package, you'll need `geom_hist` or `geom_bar` and `facet_wrap` or `facet_grid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this was done with package `ggplot2`.
Here's an example (modified from `?geom_histogram`):

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(movies, aes(x = rating)) +  
    geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.5, aes(fill = factor(Comedy))) + 
    facet_grid(Comedy~.)
```